# GetJSObject fails when run on Microsoft Surface (Excel-VBA)

Tags: javascript, excel, acrobat, tablet-pc, vba

I have written a small utility in Excel-VBA that also interacts with Acrobat Javascript in a handful of separate .pdf files.

The code has been tested extensively and runs exactly as intended on my desktop PC. However, I ultimately need to implement this code on a Microsoft Surface platform. When I try to run the same code from an Excel file on a Microsoft Surface, the code balks at any lines utilizing "GetJSObject."

Eg. The following works fine on my PC, but causes an "object or method not supported" error on my Surface.

```
Set gAPP = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

Set gPDDOC = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

If gPDDoc.Open(pdfFileName) Then Set jso = gPDDOC.GetJSObject
```

So far, I've been able to find some hints online that GetJSObject doesnt work well in a 64 bit environment and my Surface runs 64 bit Windows 10 and 32 bit Excel.

However, I don't think that this alone can account for the difference in behavior across both machines; my desktop is running 64-bit Windows 7 with 32 bit Excel, and everything works as intended.

Where should I be looking to help discover the source (and solution) of the problem?

**EDIT/UPDATE**: The getJSObject statement actually works as intended, *IF* I take the additional step of manually opening a copy of one of the relevant .pdf files in Acrobat prior to running my VBA code. I assume this means that it is somehow the object definitions (e.g. `Set gAPP = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")`) that are working differently on the Surface relative to my PC--and not the getJSObject command specifically, as originally thought?

So far, it hasnt made much sense to me how/why this could be true (let alone how I could go about resolving the issue).

Comment: Just a suggestion... Try this... change the line `If gPDDoc.Open(pdfFileName) Then Set jso = gPDDOC.GetJSObject` to `gPDDoc.Open pdfFileName : DoEvents : Set jso = gPDDOC.GetJSObject`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this had been answered yet, however there are two courses of action i'd take for research:

1.

See if you can launch it without the constructor by using:

```
Set AcroApp = New AcroApp
```

Rather than

```
Set AcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
```

2.

Ensure you are using the same version of acrobat, from my research this error occurs from the very first result in Google for the search query:

```
createobject acroexch.app error 429
You cannot do this with Adobe Reader, you need Adobe Acrobat.
```

This OLE interface is available with Adobe Acrobat, not Adobe Reader.